# What is causing this to behave strangely?

Tags: c#, .net-micro-framework

I'm working in an environment with a mostly absent double/Math library (NETMF). I wrote this class to make things easier:

```
public struct DoubleEx
{
    public const double NaN = 0.0d / 0.0d;
    public static bool IsNaN(double x)
    {
        return x != x;
    }
    ...
}
```

Seems like it should work, right?

Well, when I run this code:

```
Debug.Print("Method call: " + DoubleEx.IsNaN(DoubleEx.NaN));
Debug.Print("Method call: " + DoubleEx.NaN != DoubleEx.NaN);
```

I get this output:

```
False
True
```

Somehow, the act of putting it in a function breaks it! Is there some kind of optimization going on here? Or is the hardware misinterpreting the instructions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is based on the IEEE Standard 754:

```
// @struct IEEE_DOUBLEREP | allows bit access to 8 byte floats
//[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
//public struct ieee_doublerep
//{
//    ulong low_mantissa;       // @field low 16 bits of mantissa
//    ushort mid_mantissa;  // @field mid 16 bits of mantissa
//    uint high_mantissa:4;     // @field high 4 bits of mantissa
//    uint exponent:11;         // @field exponent of floating point number
//    uint sign:1;              // @field sign of floating point number
//};

public struct DoubleEx
{
    public const long NANMASK = 0x7FF0000000000000;
    public const long INFINITYMASK = 0x000FFFFFFFFFFFFF;

    public const double NaN = 0.0f / 0.0f;
    public const double NegativeInfinity = -1.0f / 0.0f;
    public const double PositiveInfinity = 1.0f / 0.0f;
    public static bool IsNaNBad(double x)
    {
        return x != x;
    }

    public unsafe static bool IsNaN(double value)        
    {
        long rep = *((long*)&value);
        return ((rep & NANMASK) == NANMASK &&
                ((rep & INFINITYMASK) != 0));
    }

    public unsafe static bool IsPositiveInfinity(double value)
    {
        double negInf = DoubleEx.PositiveInfinity;
        return *((long*)&value) == *((long*)&negInf);
    }

    public unsafe static bool IsNegativeInfinity(double value)
    {
        double posInf = DoubleEx.PositiveInfinity;
        return *((long*)&value) == *((long*)&posInf);
    }

    public unsafe static bool IsInfinite(double x)
    {
        long rep = *((long*)&x);
        return ((rep & NANMASK) == NANMASK &&
                ((rep & INFINITYMASK) == 0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an operator precedence problem, and putting it inside a function changes the expression.

Try:

```
Debug.Print("Method call: " + (DoubleEx.NaN != DoubleEx.NaN));
```

---

And what about:

```
static bool DoubleInequal(double a, double b) { return a != b; }
static bool IsNaN(double x) { return DoubleInequal(x, x + 0.0); }
```

Comment: @Eric: What processor are you using?  Does it have IEEE floating-point, or is .NETMF emulating floating-point operations in software, and may not even have logic for NaN at all?

Comment: A FEZ Panda II. I've asked WTF is going on on their forums [here](http://www.tinyclr.com/forum/2/3590/#/0/msg34053). I'm on a very tight deadline, and would appreciate knowing what's going on.

Comment: @Eric: Ok, found [the specs](http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/256) for that board, and [the processor](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC2387.pdf) turns out to be an ARM7TDMI.  [This other question indicates that ARM7 has to emulate operations on doubles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310907/what-are-the-advantages-of-armv7-over-armv6-when-compiling-iphone-apps), I suppose that NaN is not emulated properly.

Comment: Great. Does the same apply to floats?

Comment: @Eric: According to the other question, single-precision should be good.

Comment: Nope, singles suffer the same fate. Besides, the comparison in your answer works. It's when the NaN gets passed to a function that all fails.

Comment: @Eric: Hmmm, sounds like an invalid optimization.  What if we add another function call (will edit my answer, check back in 60 seconds)?

Comment: Still no. Getting some wierd results when I `Debug.Print(a)`: I get `-nan`! NaN's aren't signed, are they?

Comment: @Eric: IEEE returns a whole bunch of values for NaNs.  Since [the sign bit can vary between NaN values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), I suppose you could say there are both positive and negative NaNs.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `return x == NaN`?  It doesn't seem like good practice to me to assume x != x is synonymous with "IsNaN".

Comment: By definition, `NaN == x` returns false for all values of x. However, if I do add this to my code, I get the even more alarming result that `Double.IsNaN(0)` is true!

Comment: @Jason: Alarmingly, it does detect NaN. What it also does is thing 0 is NaN!