# warning when archiving my application

Tags: iphone, warnings, ad-hoc-distribution

I completed a project for a client,And it has 0 errors and 0 warnings.But on archiving it for adhoc distribution i am getting a warning that says 1."warning: all apps should include an armv7 architecture (current ARCHS = "armv6")."But i couldn't correct it.Will that application work without fail on other devices?anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can correct that by change the Build Settings.
In that, add **armv7** to the Valid Architectures field.

**Edit:**

It will work without any problem.

In addition to my comment, please see [this post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/19678/is-it-necessary-to-build-my-iphone-app-with-armv7.html) too.

Comment: It will work. But the performance would be better in latest devices if you have selected the armv7 too. For more info , look at [Brad's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310907/what-are-the-advantages-of-armv7-over-armv6-when-compiling-iphone-apps)

Answer (score 1):

please try to add armv7 with the armv6 then archive it.

I hope it will work.

Comment: As per apple introduce the ios5 which requires armv7 when you are creating distribution. that's why you got that warning. I have tried and it is works for me. just do it if it will not work then know me your deployment target. Don't affraid all is in your hand. you can also remove it